# How to modify datetime.datetime.hour in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to calculate the seconds between now and tomorrow 12:00. So I need to get tomorrow 12:00 `datetime` object.

This is pseudo code:

```
today_time = datetime.datetime.now()
tomorrow = today_time + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
tomorrow.hour = 12
result = (tomorrow-today_time).total_seconds()
```

But it will raise this error:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.datetime' objects is not writable
```

How can I modify the hour or how can I get a tomorrow 12:00 `datetime` object?

Comment: You could take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python) so you can convert **tomorrow 12:00** datetime to timestamp and then substract `time.time()`

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use the [`replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to generate a new `datetime` object based on your existing one:

```
tomorrow = tomorrow.replace(hour=12)
```

> Return a datetime with the same attributes, except for those attributes given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified. Note that `tzinfo=None` can be specified to create a naive datetime from an aware datetime with no conversion of date and time data.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
tomorrow = datetime.datetime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 12, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This is a lot more intuitive and readable answer. Thank you